# List all windows share folder details in a single command

Tags: windows, cmd, share

I know `net share` will list all the shares and by giving command `net share <sharename>` will give the details such as who has what access on that folder. Is there a way or a single command to give details on all shares in that computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does everything except omit the last status line. I am sure you can take it from here.

```
FOR /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=1" %s IN (`NET SHARE`) DO (NET SHARE %s)
```

Comment: I am glad this does what you want. Actually, this is a poor solution. It will not work well if there are long share names. And, it does not handle the last line. Perhaps I can come up with something better.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a better answer if you can run PowerShell. It is for me. I found this at https://winception.wordpress.com/2011/02/19/exporting-share-info-and-permissions-with-powershell-and-csv-files/ and made some minor changes.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
Param()
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest

# ExportShareInfo.ps1
# This script will export type 0 shares with security info, and provide a hash table of shares
# in which security info could not be found.
#
#reference: http://mow001.blogspot.com/2006/05/powershell-export-shares-and-security.html
#SID was removed from the script. Instead, the username is used to find SID when the import is run

# CHANGE TO SERVER THAT HAS SHARES TO EXPORT
$fileServer = 'localhost'

# CHANGE TO FILENAME FOR EXPORTED CSV
$filename = 'shares.csv'

$date = get-date
$datefile = get-date -uformat '%m-%d-%Y-%H%M%S'
#Store shares where security cant be found in this hash table
$problemShares = @{}

Function Get-ShareInfo($shares) {
    $arrShareInfo = @()
    Foreach ($share in $shares) {
        trap{continue;}
        Write-Verbose $share.name
        $strWMI = "\\" + $fileServer + "\root\cimv2:win32_LogicalShareSecuritySetting.Name='" + $share.name + "'"
        $objWMI_ThisShareSec = $null
        $objWMI_ThisShareSec = [wmi]$strWMI

        #In case the WMI query or 'GetSecurityDescriptor' fails, we retry a few times before adding to 'problem shares'
        For($i=0;($i -lt 5) -and ($objWMI_ThisShareSec -eq $null);$i++) {
            sleep -milliseconds 200
            $objWMI_ThisShareSec = [wmi]$strWMI
        }

        $objWMI_SD = $null
        $objWMI_SD = $objWMI_ThisShareSec.invokeMethod('GetSecurityDescriptor',$null,$null)

        For($j=0;($j -lt 5) -and ($objWMI_SD -eq $null);$j++) {
            sleep -milliseconds 200
            $objWMI_SD = $objWMI_ThisShareSec.invokeMethod('GetSecurityDescriptor',$null,$null)
        }

        If($objWMI_SD -ne $null) {
            $arrShareInfo += $objWMI_SD.Descriptor.DACL | % {
                $_ | select @{e={$share.name};n='Name'},
                @{e={$share.Path};n='Path'},
                @{e={$share.Description};n='Description'},
                AccessMask,
                AceFlags,
                AceType,
                @{e={$_.trustee.Name};n='User'},
                @{e={$_.trustee.Domain};n='Domain'}
            }
        }   
        Else {
            $ProblemShares.Add($share.name, "failed to find security info")
        }
    }
    return $arrshareInfo
}

Write-Verbose "Finding Share Security Information"

# get Shares (Type 0 is "Normal" shares) # can filter on path, etc. with where
$shares = gwmi Win32_Share -computername $fileServer -filter ætype=0'

# get the security info from shares, add the objects to an array
Write-Verbose " Complete"
Write-Verbose "Preparing Security Info for Export"

$ShareInfo = Get-ShareInfo($shares)

Write-Verbose " Complete"
Write-Verbose "Exporting to CSV"

# Export them to CSV
$ShareInfo | select Name,Path,Description,User,Domain,
AccessMask,AceFlags,AceType | export-csv -noType $filename

Write-Verbose " Complete"
Write-Verbose "Your file has been saved to $filename"

If ($problemShares.count -ge 1) {
    Write-Verbose "These Shares Failed to Export:"
}
$problemShares
```